# SQL Server Read Only Permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to GRANT Read only Permission on few Databases. How Can I achieve this in SQL Server 2005 ?

Comment: What happened when you used sp_addrolemember or don't you have permission?

Answer (score 3):

Grant the user(s) the datareader role

```
exec *THE_DATABASE_NAME*..sp_addrolemember @rolename='db_datareader', membername='*THE_USERNAME*'
```

Comment: hi dave thanks for the reply. I already tried using sp_addrolemember . Is there any other way we can GRANT Read Permissions without using sp_addrolemember ?

Comment: What happened when you used sp_addrolemember or don't you have permission?

Answer (score 0):

A quick [google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=85f&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=sql+2005+granting+read+only+permissions&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) turns up plenty of answers.

such as [this one](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Granting-permissions-in-SQL-Server-2005)...

But this question probably belongs on ServerFault.com